# Accessing GPS on Blackberry using Javascript and sending lat/long values to a server via url

Tags: javascript, iphone, blackberry, gps

When you obtain the lat/long values from a GPS enabled blackberry device, how do you send those values to a server via a url? By the way, I'm trying to do this in Javascript. `"window.location.href=..."` works fine on the iphone.

I was thinking something like this would work but it doesn't seem to:

```
function locationCB() {                                 
    window.location.href="http://www.somewebsite.com/latitude:"+blackberry.location.latitude+"/longitude:"+blackberry.location.longitude;
    return true;
}

if ( window.blackberry && blackberry.location.GPSSupported) {
        blackberry.location.onLocationUpdate("locationCB()");
        blackberry.location.setAidMode(2);
        blackberry.location.refreshLocation();
}
```

Comment: And what is current result? BB location api called successfully? any values are returned? or problem is to deliver data to server?

Comment: Have you tried `window.location = "http://..."`?

Comment: blackberry devices make the GPS coordinates THIS easy to gather from the browser?  Are there any security prompts etc?

Comment: actually there is a prompt asking for permission to acquire the lat/long points.

Answer (score 2):

I wish I had a better answer (still looking for it myself).
However, what I DO know is that most BlackBerry's don't support JavaScript.

Good news is that it is compatible with Geolocation.

Here's a link for its variables: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/Support_for_Gears_APIs_738961_11.jsp

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is to send data to server, try this:

*http://www.somewebsite.com/[page with gps gather code]**?latitude=[value]&longitude=[value]***

See
[Using URL Parameters](http://www.ironspeed.com/articles/Using%20URL%20Parameters/Article.aspx)
[How to send GPS data using HTTP to your web site](http://franson.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=5637)

Code to parse url parameters will depend on server platform

[ASP.NET Passing Parameters from One Page to Another](https://web.archive.org/web/20210612112432/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/020205-1.aspx)
[how to extract parameter from URL using PHP](http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3331869.htm)
[Java - Access parameters passed in the URL](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0049.html)